# How to return an array with even number inside a two dimension array?

Tags: javascript, loops, multidimensional-array, nested

I am trying to write a function that takes in a two dimension array and must return the vector that only contains even numbers. It is not supposed to copy the even array, just see if all numbers are even and return it.

```
var table = [ [1,2,3,4], [1,4,2,1], [9,9,9,9], [2,4,6,8] ] // -> [2,4,6,8]
```

I am not sure about the if condition and the return inside the loop, but this is what I have:

```
var getTable=function(arr) {
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++) {
      if((arr[i][j]%2)===0) {
        return arr[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: That code will return on the first even element it finds, namely the 2. You need `return arr.filter(iArr => iArr.every(e => e % 2 === 0))`, this will remove all arrays that don't contain all even numbers.

Comment: The most appropriate Array function for this task is probably [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: @ChrisG, thank you for your answer. I think this is it. I'm just having trouble implementing it (this is my first week coding). I don't fully comprehend the syntax.  What is iArr? I am trying with  ```return arr.filter(arr[i] => arr[i][j].every(e => e % 2 === 0)) ``` . but I get the error *Malformed arrow function parameter list*

Comment: I used a short arrow form (and nested an .every call inside), but you can also pass `function (iArr) { return someBooleanExpression; }`. `iArr` is short for "inner Array"; the key concept to understand how it works here is that usually, you call an existing function, and provide your own arguments, like `alert("hello")`. Here however, you provide the *function* instead, so you just name the parameters however you like, then do something with them. Longer explanation: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/xz6y51db/

Comment: @ChrisG, I am so sorry to insist but I am very inexperienced and lost (and also a bit desperate). This is a U assignment and I am positive it must be implemented just with an array.find in 1 or 2 lines of code. As I read the exercise over and over, I am almost sure it is supposed to use an arrayfind but I am very confused with the syntax. I read all over about this, I tried all the suggestions in the answers here but I haven't figured it out yet. Do you know where can I learn the syntax for an arrayfind for 2 dim array? I swear I am not asking this lightly, I have been looking around all day!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking? Did you look at the fiddle from my previous comment? Starting from line 19, there's three examples of how to do this, each one using progressively shorter syntax. Lines 20-24 should be exactly what you're looking for, no? What do you mean "you haven't figured it out"? Haven't figured out *what*, exactly? Very basic [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) example: https://jsfiddle.net/orfwtmL6/

Comment: @ChrisG, you were right. I am sooo sorry. Frustation was taking a toll on me. I just realized it made no sense to use nested fors for this and I was insisting in that, so nothing was working. Thank you so so much and I am sorry for bothering you.

Comment: No problem at all, it took me much much longer than a week to get here :) Here's a nested for loop version: https://jsfiddle.net/xvfpmq7L/

Answer (score 0):

For beginner level, you are doing fine.
Let's use a flag while checking each row.
We assume all cells are even, unless we encounter an odd cell.
We tell the cell `for` loop to finish early on odd cell (somewhat "advanced").
We return the row only if the flag is still `true`.
If the row `for` loop completes, then no all even rows found - log a message and return an empty array (`[]`).

Above, I've summarized the comments from those I've written inside the code, below.

```js
var table = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 2, 1], [9, 9, 9, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8]];

function getEvenRow(arr) {
  var allEven; // flag
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    allEven = true; // set flag to true before each row
    // stop checking row on first not even cell
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length && allEven; j++) {
      if ((arr[i][j] % 2) != 0) { // check if *not* even
        allEven = false; // not even: set flag to false
      }
    }
    if (allEven) { // was the row all even
      return arr[i]; // it was: return it (function terminates)
    }
  }
  // if we got here, none are all even.  javascript will automatically return `undefined`
  // you can console.log a message before that and return an empty array - like this:
  console.log("getEvenRow says: All even row not found");
  return [];
}

// console.log(getEvenRow(table));
// using this modification for S.O. snippet:
console.log(JSON.stringify(getEvenRow(table)));
console.log("-".repeat(40)); // just to separate the outputs

var table2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 2, 1], [9, 9, 9, 9], [2, 4, 6, 111]];

console.log(JSON.stringify(getEvenRow(table2)));
```